# Is this sentence grammatically correct (placement of helping verb)?

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-construction, verbs, conjunctions

I'm not sure about **How** and **have** here.

2 possibilities:

> a) **How** health care monitoring devices **have** helped in changing your life?
>
> b) **How have** health care monitoring devices helped in changing your life?

Which is correct here? Or both incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How have... is a question whereas How... is a statement.

> How have health care monitoring devices helped in changing your life?

Is asking the audience to answer. Whereas:

> How health care monitoring devices have helped in changing your life.

Might be the title of the paper in which you discuss the findings.

Comment: I just had doubt because **How** and **have** together looked little odd. Is it similar to the case we use **Who has done it**?

Comment: I would assume that all the same rules are applicable, since *have* is just the first/second person singular or third person plural version of *has* which is used for third person singular. I found this [site](https://englishstudypage.com/grammar/yes-no-questions-with-have/) which is nearly exactly the same as the question you asked above, which should be able to explain in a little more detail.